# GetLocatedRequest method user updates problem

Tags: geolocation, location, telegram, telethon, geo

GetLocatedRequest method is one of the most powerful method of telethon so I have researches something and I found this "updateUsersNearby". This features told us that "Returns a list of users and location-based supergroups nearby. The list of users nearby will be updated for 60 seconds after the request by the updates updateUsersNearby. The request must be sent again every 25 seconds with adjusted location to not miss new chats."

so how can I updateUsersNearby when Im using GetLocatedRequest ?

Im expecting more and updates users, so can you help me with a little code